# Snowflake / How get the original caller when a stored procedure is executed as OWNER

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a stored procedure with the behavior **execute as OWNER** (I need the owner’s rights).

I am looking to get the original role of the user that called it, is there any way to do that?
Unfortunately, as expected  the `select current_role()` statement returns the owner's role ...

If a workaround exists, I would appreciate if you could describe it to me.

Following Mike's advice:there the code I done to test Harsh's solution:

Failed again ^^
There's my code. May be you ll see my mistake.

```
create or replace procedure do_noting_proc()
returns string
language javascript
execute as OWNER
AS
$$
 var retour="Resultat";
 try{
   rs0=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:"SELECT $QUERY_TAG;"}).execute();
   cR=rs0.getColumnValue(1);
   return "QRValue= "+callerRole;        
 }catch(err){
    return "do_noting_proc KO: "+ err.message+";";
 }
$$;

create or replace procedure test_proc()
returns string
language javascript
execute as CALLER
AS
$$
var rString="Result -->";
try{
  rs0=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:"SELECT CURRENT_ROLE();"}).execute();
  rs0.next();
  cr="testQT"+rs0.getColumnValue(1);
  snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:"alter session set QUERY_TAG="+cr+";"}).execute();
  rs=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:"call  PUBLIC.do_noting_proc();"}).execute();
  rs.next();
  rString+=rs.getColumnValue(1);
}catch(err){
    return "test_proc: "+ err.message+";";
}
return "test_proc : "+rString;
$$;
```

Then`call share_view_or_table();`
==>test_proc : ** Result -->do_noting_proc KO: Use of session variable '$QUERY_TAG' is not allowed in owners rights stored procedure;**
(procedure created by sysadmin and Executed as sysadmin)

Also if I run 'code' 
   select $QUERY_TAG;

I get the error: **SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 Session variable '$QUERY_TAG' does not exist**

whereas

```
SHOW PARAMETERs LIKE 'QUERY_TAG' IN SESSION ;
```

works fine and print **TESTQTSYSADMIN**

@Harsh many thanks for your time

Comment: Do you mean from within the SP?

Comment: I missed your comment (sorry Mike). Yes that's it, from within the stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

When using `EXECUTE AS OWNER` the [rules do not permit reading the caller's session details](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights.html#owner-s-rights-stored-procedures), including their identity or role:

> Owner’s rights stored procedures adhere to the following rules within a session:
>
> […]
>
> - Cannot access most caller-specific information. For example:
> - Cannot view, set, or unset the caller’s session variables.
> - Can read only specific session parameters, and cannot set or unset any of the caller’s session parameters.
> - Cannot query INFORMATION_SCHEMA table functions, such as AUTOMATIC_CLUSTERING_HISTORY, that return results based on the current user.

While inconvenient, you can use logic within the stored procedure to enforce that the role name of the caller should be passed as an argument:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC(ROLE_NAME STRING)
[…]
var VALID_ROLES_ARRAY = ["FOO", "BAR"];
var IS_VALID_CALLER_ROLENAME = VALID_ROLES_ARRAY.includes(ROLE_NAME);
[…];

CALL PROC(CURRENT_ROLE());
```

Comment: Hi Harsh,
Thank you for your help.
There is something that I missed out when I try to get the query_tag session parameter with "SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'QUERY_TAG';" I get: 
 Erreur do_nothing_proc(): Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'SHOW PARAMETER'.; 
(do_nothing_proc() is executed as OWNER by the procedure TEST() exceuted as CALLER)
Any idea?

Comment: it's not working. I added a new answer with the code (to much char to post a new comment)

Comment: Thank you Harsh.That's what i ended up that's what i ended up concluding. I think the documentation is not very clear on theses points.May be you have deducted, but the goal is to control the use of the procedure according  the parameters. Finally, I succeeded by  using the "curent_user()" function and user's roles retreived from the view 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.APPLICABLE_ROLES '